# Does a C++17/20 compiler optimize returning a local varaible by copy elision or invoking move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, copy-elision

Say we have a class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(const Foo&) = default;
  Foo(Foo&&) = default;
  // other functions...
private:
  // a bunch of data members...
};
```

Would a C++17/C++20 compiler optimize the following return statement?

```
Foo CreateFoo() {
  Foo foo;
  // Do more things with foo ...
  return foo;  // Is copy elision used here? If not, would it be optimized as return std::move(foo)?
}
```

Comment: Usually, but not required. See NVRO

Comment: Compiler is not required to elide the move, but may do so. Whether compilers actually will is largely dependent on what "_// Doing more things with foo ..._" is. It isn't guaranteed in all scenarios that `foo` will be the object returned, so it is impossible to _always_ do the elision and compilers detect this to different degree. (Nothing about this has changed since C++98.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior has not changed since C++11.  A named object *may* be elided, provided it meets certain requirements, but it is not required.

What is guarnateed is that the object will first be treated as an rvalue for the purposes of overload resolution and if that fails then in fails back to lvalue overload resoltution.  In this case that means at worst `foo` will be moved out of the function if the elision, Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO), does not happen.

Comment: Do you have any reference?

Comment: The behavior is unchanged since C++98 even (with respect to elision, not implicit move). The rule for implicit move in return statements has somewhat significantly changed in C++23 however (although OP asked only for C++17/20). Since C++23 the id-expression in the return statement is simply a xvalue if it is implicitly-movable. No two-phase overload resolution anymore.

Comment: @xuhdev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088023/is-an-object-guaranteed-to-be-moved-when-it-is-returned and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Non-mandatory_copy.2Fmove_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29_elision