std::transform and moving/copying the result
I am not very well-versed in C++, so I fail to understand how std::transform handles this situation: I have a vector result of length 6. This should correspond to number of files being processed for reading the data. I process these files in parallel where each call of lambda function returns an std::vector. I would like to store those to result, while making result a vector of vectors (where length of outer length is 6 and of inner vector is unknown and depending on the length of file being processed).
I tried to make a very simplified example processing yet another vector instead of actual text files. This std::transform in such form works for me, but I fail to understand what is happening: is the result copied from the lambda function return to the result vector? If yes, how can I move it instead of copying? Is there any other way to perform this which is more efficient? What should I learn to understand these intrinsics without asking StackOverflow each time? :) Thanks.
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Point3Di {
    double timestamp;
    int x, y, z;
};

Point3Di parseLine(const std::string& line) {
    Point3Di point;
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> point.timestamp >> point.x >> point.y >> point.z;
    return point;
}

int main() {
    const int num_vectors = 6;
    std::vector<std::vector<Point3Di>> result(num_vectors);

    std::vector<std::string> lines = {
        "1.0 1 2 3", "2.0 4 5 6", "3.0 7 8 9",
        "4.0 10 11 12", "5.0 13 14 15", "6.0 16 17 18",
        "7.0 19 20 21", "8.0 22 23 24", "9.0 25 26 27",
        "10.0 28 29 30", "11.0 31 32 33", "12.0 34 35 36"
    };

    size_t num_lines = lines.size();

    // Indices for splitting the lines among vectors
    std::vector<size_t> indices(num_vectors + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= num_vectors; ++i) {
        indices[i] = i * (num_lines / num_vectors);
    }

    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, indices.begin(), indices.end() - 1,
                   result.begin(),
                   [&](size_t start) {
                       size_t end = start + (num_lines / num_vectors);
                       std::vector<Point3Di> temp_vector;
                       for (size_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
                           temp_vector.push_back(parseLine(lines[i]));
                       }
                       return temp_vector;
                   });

    return 0;
}

UPD:
Simplified version with just reserving a vector without filling real values:
int main() {
    const int num_vectors = 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<Point3Di>> result(num_vectors);

    // Indices for splitting the lines among vectors
    std::vector<size_t> indices(num_vectors );
    for (int i = 0; i <= num_vectors; ++i) {
        indices[i] = 1;
    }

    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                   result.begin(),
                   [&](size_t start) {
                       std::vector<Point3Di> temp_vector;
                       temp_vector.reserve(10000000);
                       return temp_vector;
                   });

    return 0;


A smart compiler with optimizations on will probably elide a copy construction, but you can say return std::move(temp_vector) to enforce move.

And as long as you're interested in performance, you should pre-allocate space for temp_vector since you know it will hold end-start elements

Don't return std::move(temp_vector);. It achieves nothing at best and inhibits optimizations. return temp_vector; is perfect.

@j6t that's a bit of an overreaction I think. Compilers are not obligated to implement NRVO, and if they don't then OPs code incurs a copy-construction without it. Unless the compiler and version is guaranteed ahead of time, or compiler-specific code is written, then enforcing a move is a great idea.

@AndyG -- compiler is required to do move on return if it can't do return value optimization.

@Gene: For all I know the standard has changed last I checked on this, but my understanding is that only RVO is required and NRVO is still not required by any compiler. I believe people are trying to change this.

@AndyG -- nothing has changed since C++17 required compilers do move on return, don't confuse with NRVO.

@Gene I wasn't aware of any C++17 requirement on performing a move on an lvalue in  a return statement. Can you please link the section?

@AndyG -- since C++11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088023/is-an-object-guaranteed-to-be-moved-when-it-is-returned

@gene I think you're right but the SO answers and standardese wording circa c++11 are wrong because they explicitly refer to function parameters. The wording in class.copy has been changed to require the move ctor to be called if it can now.

The return temp_vector; matches the case for named return value optimization. This permits, but does not require, an implementation to construct the local temp_vector in the storage of the result, rather than copy it to the result. The major C++ implementations all do this.
You are however copying your values into temp_vector, and copying them as the storage for temp_vector is expanded. You can avoid these copies by adding a constructor of Point3Di and passing the lines to it, and reserving space in temp_vector.
struct Point3Di {
    double timestamp;
    int x, y, z;

    Point3Di() = default;
    Point3Di(std::istream&& iss) {
        iss >> timestamp >> x >> y >> z;
    }
};

std::vector<Point3Di> temp_vector;
temp_vector.reserve(num_lines / num_vectors);
for (size_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    temp_vector.emplace_back(std::istringstream(lines[i]));
}

